# StopIteration Error when using next in Python 3 using nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, nltk, stopiteration

I want to run a code in Python 3. It works in Python 2.7 and the input is not empty. Some parts of the code are as follows:

```
parser = nltk.ChartParser(zinc_grammar.GCFG)
parse_trees = [next(parser.parse(t)) for t in tokens]
```

But it shows the StopIteration error on the bottom line. Does anyone know how to solve it? Is there any alternative for it?

Comment: The code you show does not provide enough information about the problem, please provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you think of a reason that `parser.parse(t)` might produce an empty sequence? What do you think should happen when you use `next` with an empty sequence? What does the documentation say about that? What happened when you tried putting `python next stopiteration` into a search engine?

Comment: Show us the `try...except` code that raised this error.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem is from the definition of the `tokens` because I used `lambda` function. I changed it and the problem is solved.